# how to using javascript function in smarty tpl

Tags: javascript, function, smarty

i have a fake visitor's counter script which code in javascript but i want to use it in smarty tpl file i am try to do it but its not displaying where i want. the script code is below

```
<!--Simply copy and paste it where you wish the counter to appear.-->


<SCRIPT language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
// counter - from http://rainbow.arch.scriptmania.com/scripts
function fakecounter(){

//decrease/increase counter value (depending on perceived popularity of your site!)
var decrease_increase=2460

var counterdate=new Date()
var currenthits=counterdate.getTime().toString()
currenthits=parseInt(currenthits.substring(2,currenthits.length-4))+decrease_increase

document.write("You are visitor # <b>"+currenthits+"</b> to my site!")
}
fakecounter()
</script>
```

and i am trying to using it in after `</script>` .

Answer (score 1):

This script should work without a problem. If you put it in clean Smarty template file you get information similar to:

> You are visitor # 945155 to my site!

However in older versions of smarty you need to use `{literal}` to use JavaScript, so your code should look like this:

```
<!--Simply copy and paste it where you wish the counter to appear.-->


<SCRIPT language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    {literal}
    // counter - from http://rainbow.arch.scriptmania.com/scripts
    function fakecounter() {

//decrease/increase counter value (depending on perceived popularity of your site!)
        var decrease_increase = 2460

        var counterdate = new Date()
        var currenthits = counterdate.getTime().toString()
        currenthits = parseInt(currenthits.substring(2, currenthits.length - 4)) + decrease_increase

        document.write("You are visitor # <b>" + currenthits + "</b> to my site!")
    }
    fakecounter()
    {/literal}
</script>
```